# Npm commands to execute scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

```json
"scripts": {
  "release": "npm run release| tee output1.txt",
  "build":"npm run build | tee output.txt"
},
```

Then I used:

```
npm run release
```

Output:Killed

Please help I pass two test cases one is remaining

Comment: Looks like you're calling the same script within itself: `npm run release`, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are expecting.

```
"scripts": {
  "release": "npm -v && node -v",
  "build":"node index.js"
}
```

run below commands and you can get the output as expected.

```
npm run release| tee output1.txt

npm run build | tee output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can combine scripts by && operator. They will be executed one by one

```
"scripts": { "release": "npm run release && tee output1.txt", "build":"npm run build && tee output.txt" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripts tag is generally used to automate repetitive tasks. You can define any number of these.

```
"scripts": {
  "release": "npm run release| tee output1.txt && npm run build | tee output.txt",
},
```

The && is referred to as AND_IF  helps you to run both the commands in sequence that means if first command fails to execute it won't run the next command.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for [post scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts):

```
"scripts": {
  "release": "do something",
  "postrelease": "tee output1.txt",
  "build": "do something different",
  "postbuild": "tee output.txt"
},
```